# Number of ideals of a PID modulo an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a Principal Ideal Domain and $(a)\neq(0)$ an ideal of $R$. Prove $R/(a)$ has a finite number of ideals.

Comment: Hint: the ideals of $R/(a)$ are in bijection with the ideals of $R$ that contain $(a)$.

Comment: Indeed, I have tried to descompose R/(a) using the prime factorization of a.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your statement is equivalent to proving (why?) that there are finitely many ideals $(b)$ such that $(a) \subset (b)$. But, $(a) \subset (b)$ iff $b|a$. Now factor $a$ into a finite product of irreducibles and use the fact that a P.I.D. is a U.F.D. to show that there can be only finitely many possibilities for $b$ such that $b|a$.